# Yii TinyMCE extension doesn't load css on subdomain

Tags: css, yii, tinymce

I have Yii application at **site.com/module** with tinymce extension installed.
But it doesn't load tinymce CSS files when I open the same application via sub-domain alias **module.site.com**.
All JS files are loading properly.

Comment: what kind of paths do you use? (relativ ones?)

Comment: Yes. I'm using `application.extensions.tinymce.ETinyMce`

Comment: sry, that info does not help me in any way

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes the widget we use does not load css, so we need to load them externally, this can be achieved with using Yii Assest Manager.

```
<?php
$assetUrl = Yii::app()->getAssetManager()->publish(Yii::getPathOfAlias('ext.tinymce.assets'));
Yii::app()->clientScript->registerCssFile($assetUrl.'/example.css'); 
?>
```